# Comparing two strings in c++

Tags: c++, string

I am getting a weird problem in comparing two string in c++.

c  pointing to  "dreamy"  , which I have confirmed from the printf statement.  Now I want to compare this  with "dreamy"  string  but every time it is going in else part and showing not matching.

cout statement of both Str1 and Str2  also printing same   output "dreamy"  but the length of Str1 is showing 7 and length of Str2 is  6.

Can anybody tell me what is the problem and how to fix it.

Thanks.

```
        char *c;
        c = strtok (temp,",");   
                    // Here   printf ("%s\n",c);   prints    dreamy
        while (c != NULL)
        {
            std::string Str1 = std::string(c);
            std::string Str2 = std::string("dreamy");
            cout << "Str1  " << Str1 << "Len" << Str1.length() <<endl;  //  Len = 7 showing for  c = "dreamy"
            cout << "Str2  " << Str2 << "Len" << Str2.length() <<endl;  //  Len = 6 for "dreamy"
            if(Str1.compare(Str2) == 0)
            {
                cout << "Finally Match";
                presence[1] = 1;
            }
            else
                cout << " Dont Match";
            printf ("%s\n",c);
```

Comment: What's in `temp`? And please show the exact output of your `cout <<` statements.

Comment: NPE answer helped me.
There was a space after "dreamy "  after strtok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Len = 7` suggests there's a spurious character in the first string (perhaps a space or a newline).

Comment: That's why I like to print string using `cout << '[' << str << ']'` :)